# Install HAProxy 2 on Centos 7

Tags: centos7, haproxy

Where can I find official documentation on HAproxy 2x installation documentation for Centos 7?

```
$ yum install haproxy
$ haproxy -v
HA-Proxy version 1.5.18 2016/05/10
Copyright 2000-2016 Willy Tarreau <willy@haproxy.org>

$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"
```

I would like to not run an outdated, potentially insecure version of the product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HAProxy from the repo is unlikely to be insecure as long as CentOS7 is supported, but yes, the 1.5 version is outdated functionality-wise.

From what I see, only modern Fedora versions have more modern versions of HAProxy in their official repositories. If you purchase a commercial version of HAProxy it looks as though there's a RHEL/CentOS compatible repository supported directly by the HAProxy people. Otherwise you may actually have to compile and roll your own packages for your environment.

If running another distro is a possible workaround, the most user-friendly effort for the community version of HAProxy seems to exist on the Debian and Ubuntu side of things: https://haproxy.debian.net/

Comment: Fedora [EPEL](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/epel/#_el7) also provides a more modern version of HAProxy for CentOS/RHEL 7, even HAProxy 1.8 offered there is too old to satisfy the initial request.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to install the latest version [`HAProxy 2.4.2 (LTS)`](http://www.haproxy.org/) on `CentOS 7` by executing the steps [from this blog,](https://idolsgate.com/blog/how-to-install-the-latest-version-of-haproxy-on-centos-7/) Here they are in case the link goes down, I've modified them a bit because the blog talks about 2.0 version while I needed the latest:

### Steps

###### Choose the haproxy branch

The 1st step defines the branch you are going to install, If you want latest of `2.0` just modify the URL to the branch you want, you'll have to repeat that change in every step you see an URL:

```sh
LATEST_HAPROXY=$(wget -qO-  http://www.haproxy.org/download/2.4/src/ | egrep -o "haproxy-2\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+" | head -1)
```

###### Download and install the package:

```sh
cd /usr/src/
wget http://www.haproxy.org/download/2.4/src/${LATEST_HAPROXY}.tar.gz
tar xzvf ${LATEST_HAPROXY}.tar.gz
yum install gcc-c++ openssl-devel pcre-static pcre-devel systemd-devel -y
cd /usr/src/${LATEST_HAPROXY}
make TARGET=linux-glibc USE_PCRE=1 USE_OPENSSL=1 USE_ZLIB=1 USE_CRYPT_H=1 USE_LIBCRYPT=1 USE_SYSTEMD=1
mkdir /etc/haproxy
make install
```

###### Create a systemd service /usr/lib/systemd/system/haproxy.service

```
cat > /usr/lib/systemd/system/haproxy.service << 'EOL'
   
    [Unit]
    Description=HAProxy Load Balancer
    After=syslog.target network.target
    
    
    [Service]
    Environment="CONFIG=/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg" "PIDFILE=/run/haproxy.pid"
    ExecStartPre=/usr/local/sbin/haproxy -f $CONFIG -c -q
    ExecStart=/usr/local/sbin/haproxy -Ws -f $CONFIG -p $PIDFILE
    ExecReload=/usr/local/sbin/haproxy -f $CONFIG -c -q
    ExecReload=/bin/kill -USR2 $MAINPID
    KillMode=mixed
    Restart=always
    SuccessExitStatus=143
    Type=notify
    
    
    [Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target
EOL
```

###### Create /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg

```
cat > /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg << 'EOL'

    global
     log /dev/log local0
     log /dev/log local1 notice
     daemon
    
    
    defaults
     log global
     option dontlognull
     timeout connect 50000
     timeout client  50000
     timeout server  50000
    
    
    listen ListenName
            bind *:80
            mode tcp
            server YourServer 127.0.0.1:80
EOL
```

###### Restart HAProxy and verify bash

```
systemctl start haproxy
systemctl status haproxy
```

Answer (score 3):

Found this project on github, if you need to produce RPMs of the latest haproxy versions.

https://github.com/DBezemer/rpm-haproxy

### Steps

#### Install dev dependencies.

```
sudo yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'
```

#### Checkout the repo and switch to the branch for the version you want.

```
cd /opt
git clone https://github.com/DBezemer/rpm-haproxy.git 
cd ./rpm-haproxy
git checkout 2.4
```

#### Build the RPMS

```
make
```

Resulting RPMs will be in `./RPMS/`

#### Update your version by running

```
sudo rpm -U haproxy-2.4.9-1.amzn1.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Your answer suggests a workable solution to the question is available via another website. The Stack Exchange family of Q&A websites [generally frowns on this type of answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). Please read [How do I write a good answer?](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer) and consider revising your answer to include the steps required to resolve the issue. And don't forget to take the [site tour](http://serverfault.com/tour).

Answer (score 2):

You can install the latest from:
http://au1.mirror.crc.id.au/repo/el7-extra/x86_64/

puppet example:

```
    yumrepo { "haproxy-repo":
        baseurl => "http://au1.mirror.crc.id.au/repo/el7-extra/x86_64/",
        gpgkey => "http://au1.mirror.crc.id.au/repo/RPM-GPG-KEY-kernel-xen",
        descr => "haproxy",
        enabled => 1,
        gpgcheck => 1
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Until the instructions for HAProxy 2.0 are available, you can install HAProxy 1.8 by following the instructions at this url: https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/rh-haproxy18/